# Coordicide in 2021?

Tags: iota-network, coordinator, asktheexperts

**Billy, how likely is it from your current point of view to expect Coordicide on mainnet within 2021?**

Virtually certain (>99%)

Very likely (>90%)

Likely (>66%)

About as likely as not (33 to 66%)

Unlikely (<33%)

Very unlikely (<10%)

Exceptionally unlikely (<1%)

Comment: Unfortunately, StackExchange does not work well for opinion-based questions. :-(

Answer (score 2):

It depends on development time and network maturation. The more nodes and transactions there are, the more likely the network is mature and ready in time for release.

Answer (score 1):

This Stackexchange is meant to answer technical questions not speculation or opinion based ones. Please remove the question.